# spin–orbit resonance, between moon and the earth

Tags: orbit, the-moon, earth

if this happens in the future what will be the consecuences of this?.
Consecuences for the life or the climate conditions.

Comment: What do you think would happen?

Comment: There already is a spin-orbit resonance between the Earth and the Moon. We only see one side of the Moon as a result.

Comment: Doing some research is encouraged before asking questions here.   As pointed out above, the Moon is already in spin-orbit resonance with the Earth.   Many moons are around their planets and Mercury is around the sun.    Any close orbit usually ends up this way.    Are you asking what would happen if the Earth was in spin-orbit resonance with the Moon?   That probably won't happen.  It will take longer than the sun will live, but what theoretically might happen isn't hard to look up.

Comment: Maybe Im  not be sufficient clear. Im reffer in when the earth and moon have the same spin orbit-face, the same face the moon, and the same face earth to the moon.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to happen, but if it did, what it would mean is that the Earth would rotate very slowly, at the same rate the Moon orbits the Earth, currently 27.3 days, but for practical purposes, [29.5 days relative to the sun](https://community.dur.ac.uk/john.lucey/users/lunar_sid_syn.html).   Presumably even longer, because as the Earth slows, the Moon moves further away, so figure 30-something days for 1 synodic orbit.   I'll say 30 days, but it would probably be a bit longer.

That means that a complete day/night cycle would be 720 hours.  Days might be scorching hot and nights would get very cold and as a result, you'd probably see stronger winds, but the Coriolis effect would be measurably decreased, so prevailing winds might be less, or perhaps similar to Venus, where the upper atmosphere rotates in one direction very fast.

You might see fewer hurricanes.  Snow would probably all melt during the day, so there would be less chance of permanent snow buildup outside of very cold regions that get very little solar energy during winter.  Plants would also need to adapt to 360 hours of sunlight and 360 hours of night.

There would be no more tides and it's possible that the Moon's orbit and the slowing of the Earth's relatively rapid rotation assists the magnetic field so we might lose the Magnetic field too - which would be pretty harmful to life in the long run.

The Moon would also stay in essentially the same place in the sky all the time.  That's a product of tidal locking.

That's the gist of it anyway, but feel free to comment if I skipped anything.

Comment: Your statement "a 24 hour day would be 720 hours" made me think for a few seconds (much longer than I'm used to). It might be clearer to say "a full day/night cycle would be 720 hours", or even use the word "nycthemeron" for "full day/night cycle".

Comment: @Jim421616 Edits made.  I think that's a little clearer.   Thanks.